# How to make readonly a field with attrs and these conditions?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

```html
<field name="Tr"   attrs="{'readonly':['|',('week_end','=',False),('HSup_P1','!=',False),('HSup_P2','!=',False),('HSup_P3','!=',False),('HSup_P4','!=',False)]}"/>
```

What I want to do is to make this field *readonly* when `week_end` is *False* or `HSup_P1`, `HSup_P2` , `HSup_P3` or `HSup_P4` are *True*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<field name="Tr" attrs="{'readonly': ['|', '|', ('week_end', '=', False), ('HSup_P1', '!=', False), '|', '|', ('HSup_P2', '!=', False), ('HSup_P3', '!=', False), ('HSup_P4', '!=', False)]}"/>
```

Take a look at my answer in this post: [I don´t understand Normal Polish Notation (NPN or PN). How to build a complex domain in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523138/i-don%C2%B4t-understand-normal-polish-notation-npn-or-pn-how-to-build-a-complex-do/48525758#48525758)

I think it will help you in the future when you have to deal with domains and this Polish Notation.

So if you apply the method I suggest you in the link:

```
A => ('week_end', '=', False)
B => ('HSup_P1', '!=', False)
C => ('HSup_P2', '!=', False)
D => ('HSup_P3', '!=', False)
E => ('HSup_P4', '!=', False)
```

What you want:

```
Step 0. => A or B or C or D or E
```

Here you can group the letters as you want, since there aren't any priorities, so for example:

```
Step 1. => A or B or C or D or E
Step 2. => AB or C or D or E
Step 3. => AB or CD or E
Step 4. => AB or CDE
```

Now, we decompose the made groups, moving their operators to the left side:

```
Step 4. => or AB CDE
Step 3. => or AB or CD E
Step 2. => or AB or or C D E
Step 1. => or or A B or or C D E
```

Finally, replace the letters by their respective expressions and the operators too (`or` by `|`, `and` by `&amp;`), and you'll get the answer I wrote you above.