# Multiple conditions in domain odoo 8

Tags: xml, odoo

I have a domain that I want to make a condition.

> A or B or C or D

What would be the syntax in XML ? I have tried many syntax's but it did not work.

```
<field name="domain" >['|', ('sav_diag_check_cd','=',1),('sav_diag_check_cc','=',1),'|',('sav_diag_check_pe','=',1),('sav_diag_check_fe','=',1)]  </field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

[I don´t understand Normal Polish Notation (NPN or PN). How to build a complex domain in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523138/i-don%C2%B4t-understand-normal-polish-notation-npn-or-pn-how-to-build-a-complex-do)

If you understand the explanation I give in my answer, you will never have any problem with Normal Polish Notation. Your case will be solved with:

```
['|', '|', ('sav_diag_check_cd', '=', 1), ('sav_diag_check_cc', '=', 1), '|', ('sav_diag_check_pe', '=', 1), ('sav_diag_check_fe', '=' ,1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much for this prompt answer, maybe I did not really understand your previous answer, I will focus on it, thank you again man.

Comment: I actually would use `['|','|','|',A,B,C,D]` but your solution is correct too.